# Cucumber's ANSI colors messing up emacs compilation buffer

Tags: emacs, cucumber

When working in Emacs, I use the compile command (F12 by default) to run programs.  When I run Cucumber in Emacs, Cucumber spits out ANSI colors that the Emacs compilation mode doesn't interpret.  The result is ugly and hard to read.  Here's a snippet of the *compilation* buffer showing the ugly:

```
^[[31m(::) failed steps (::)^[[0m
```

The command I'm using:

```
( cd ~/lab/rails/todolist && rake cucumber:all )
```

Versions:

- Emacs 23.1
- Cucumber 0.8.3
- Cucumber-rails 0.3.2

The world would be sunshine and birds singing if I could:

- Get Emacs to interpret ANSI color codes in its compilation buffer, or
- Get Cucumber to stop spitting out ANSI color codes

Any ideas?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I use this  to turn on ansi color interpretation in my compilation buffer:

```el
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately, in my environment (cygwin-xemacs) it kroaked on  (buffer-read-only #<buffer "*compilation*">) with "Error in process filter", which seems very strange. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked great for me, too.  I also added `(linum-mode 0)` (and, at first attempt `(line-number-mode 0)`, which didn't work, but I left in anyway, and might work for someone else), after `(toggle-read-only)`, which makes me even that much happier (a bunch of lines that were just barely wrapping now don't).

Comment: I decided to add some colour to my makefiles output and hit this issue in emacs. Great solution!

Comment: For modern Emacsen, one should let-bind `inhibit-read-only` to `t`, instead of calling `toggle-read-only`.

Comment: Any way to make this work even as new text is being added? I tested that on the result of `ack`, but the hook seems to be run before the content fills the buffer, so the content is no interpreted.

Answer (score 22):

I improve code so it doesn't pollute `M-x grep` like commands and more efficient:

```el
(ignore-errors
  (require 'ansi-color)
  (defun my-colorize-compilation-buffer ()
    (when (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode)
      (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point-max))))
  (add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'my-colorize-compilation-buffer))
```

Comment: **Note** I test this code only with Emacs 24.x, it may not work in version 23.x or less...

Comment: This works fine, why `(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)` does not?

Answer (score 8):

As of 2023, the most modern way appears to be the `xterm-color` Emacs package.

1. Execute `M-x package-install` with `xterm-color`.
2. Add the following lines to your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```el
(require 'xterm-color)
(setq compilation-environment '("TERM=xterm-256color"))
(defun my/advice-compilation-filter (f proc string)
  (funcall f proc (xterm-color-filter string)))
(advice-add 'compilation-filter :around #'my/advice-compilation-filter)
```

(See [xterm-color documentation](https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color#usage).)

Note that this will provide an error message if `xterm-color` was not installed properly. This is strongly advised, because on an incomplete Emacs installation it will clearly explain to you what's wrong, instead of leaving you wondering why the colors don't work.

However, if you really prefer to **not being informed** if `xterm-color` is missing, use instead:

```el
(when (require 'ansi-color nil t)
  (setq compilation-environment '("TERM=xterm-256color"))
  (defun my/advice-compilation-filter (f proc string)
    (funcall f proc (xterm-color-filter string)))
  (advice-add 'compilation-filter :around #'my/advice-compilation-filter))
```

Comment: This worked well for coloring my pytest compilation commands, but broke my ag-mode - it lost interactivity and slowed down.

Comment: @simno I'd propose to file a bug report: https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color/issues

Comment: There's one already for `rg.el` and `ag.el` packages: https://github.com/dajva/rg.el/issues/65. Both packages rely on matching terminal color escapes and do not provide option to ignore highlighting. I'd switch off `my/advice-compilation-filter` for specifically `ag-mode`, but I'll have to figure it out.

Comment: This didn't work for sbt color output in the *compilation* buffer for me. The escape codes still printed.

Comment: works great for mypy errors

Comment: actually there is a weird issue with this -- I have the compilation buffer in one frame and a source buffer in the other frame, and I have a keybinding setup to trigger compilation regardless of which frame/buffer I'm using. If the compilation buffer has focus and I press the key, I get colors. If the source buffer has focus, then no colors.