# emacs strips away all ansi color codes in shells -- AGAIN

Tags: shell, emacs, ansi-colors

This seems to be a duplicate
of [emacs strips away all ansi color codes in shells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245486/emacs-strips-away-all-ansi-color-codes-in-shells)
but it's not!

It differs in that I cannot only see any ansi-color but that I cannot EVEN see the raw escape color codes (that should be there regarding the conversation and comments at the referred question).

I am on OSX (10.10.2) and GNU EMACS (official dl: http://emacsformacosx.com/)

Here are the simple steps to reproduce my problem:

`emacs -q` 
goto `*scratch*` buffer and execute:

```lisp
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "bash")

(require 'ansi-color)

(ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

Then:

```
M-x shell
```

Now execute some shell commands that should return ansi-colors.

In my case there is nothing! I spent hours and hours checking and trying out all he answerers about ansi-colors -- no success. Above remained just the minimal steps.

Thank you all for helping me out.

p.s.: funny enough, if I use `M-x ansi-term` or even `M-x eshell` both of them show ansi-colors right out of the box!

Comment: Are you running in a graphical window, or inside Terminal.app?

Comment: I have tested it in terminal: Terminal.app and iTerm2 `emacs -q` als well as running Emacs.app with no `.emacs` or `.emacs.d`. Btw. my bash is the standard /bin/bash shipping with osx: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Just note: the bash that starts emacs has the envir var `$TERM` set to `xterm-256color` . The "shell" in shell-mode has this var set to `dumb` whitch is the emacs standard and expected.

Comment: @Chris Concerning the present issue, may I ask on what the question about Terminal.app was aiming at? In what ways is it relevant to problem?

Comment: Emacs as a standalone graphical application handles its own colours. Inside a terminal, it is limited by the colours and colour depth offered by the terminal. I was just trying to eliminate that limitation as a cause of your problem.

Comment: @Chris Thank you Chris for clarifying. I am aware of this and that's why I think it is all the more strange having working ansi-colors in eshell but not in shell mode. If you start `emacs -q` on the command line and then carry out the three commands in the *scratch* buffer above, what is your outcome. Do you actually have colors?

Comment: I didn't get more involved with this question because I virtually never use `M-x shell` and I'm not sure that I can help very much. I get some colours, but not the ones I would expect. When I type commands, `--flags` are red. My bash prompt contains `>`, which is blue. Executed commands are black, but bold. I don't get coloured output from `ls`, for example. Setting `$TERM` to `xterm-256color` *does* give me coloured output from `ls`, but you seem to think that this should work even if it is `dumb`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Chris for reporting and checking on your side! The issue was solved in two steps:

1. indeed, set $TERM to `xterm-256color`
2. use *GNU* `ls --color` but not the `ls` shipping with the MacOS.