# ANSI Coloring in Compilation Mode

Tags: shell, emacs, text-coloring, ansi-escape, compilationmode

Have anyone added support for ansi-color in compilation-mode Emacs? If so what property/attribute does the color-writing program have to check for in order to make sure its active terminal supports ANSI-escape coloring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cucumber's ANSI colors messing up emacs compilation buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072648/cucumbers-ansi-colors-messing-up-emacs-compilation-buffer)

Comment: I will always initially see "ANSI Coloring-In Competition Mode".

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There's already a function for applying color to comint buffers.  You simply need to enable it on compilation buffers:

```lisp
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()
  (toggle-read-only)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point))
  (toggle-read-only))
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)
```

Color writing programs should check the `TERM` environment variable and the terminfo database to check if the terminal supports color.  In practice, a lot of programs ignore this and rely on a user setting.  Emacs will set the compilation terminal type to `dumb` by default but this can be overriden by setting the `compilation-environment` variable.

*Update*: Note that in Emacs 24.5 the two calls to `(toggle-read-only)` in the code above  are not needed.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work completely. I tested with `grep --color` and sometimes larger regions get colorized that shouldn't be. It seems like Emacs doesn't always detect disabling ANSI control sequences :(

Comment: @Nordlöw, I've fixed this issue, and updated the post. The function was trying to colorize the whole buffer, although it should filter only the chunk that is spilled from a process. Although the new version is much more robust and fast, it can still be confused, since it is not guaranteed, that a process will not cut his output in the middle of escape sequence.

Comment: Using Emacs 24.5, it seems the (toggle-read-only) calls are unnecessary.

Comment: In emacs 27.2 the call `(ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point))` inevitably seems to result in a "Marker does not point anywhere" error.

Answer (score 35):

My optimized solution which don't pollute `M-x grep` (only for `M-x compile`):

```el
(ignore-errors
  (require 'ansi-color)
  (defun my-colorize-compilation-buffer ()
    (when (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode)
      (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point-max))))
  (add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'my-colorize-compilation-buffer))
```

Comment: Thank you! When I was using something more like the accepted answer above, my rgrep buffers were showing in a solid red font. Your version is working much better for me. Using emacs 24.3.50.1.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a better solution.  Using `compilation-filter-start` should be much more efficient than re-coloring everything between `(point-min)` and `(point-max)` each time.

Comment: To make this work I needed to set the compilation-environment variable to TERM=xterm-256color.

Answer (score 15):

As of emacs 28.1, this is now a built in !

```
(require 'ansi-color)
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'ansi-color-compilation-filter)
```

Or with use-package

```
(use-package ansi-color
    :hook (compilation-filter . ansi-color-compilation-filter))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing both the imperative and the declarative way of configuring this!

Answer (score 8):

Riffing on @stribb's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044536/179332), which riffs on @gavenkoa's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788581/179332), this is how to set it up with the awesome [use-package](https://jwiegley.github.io/use-package/):

```lisp
(use-package ansi-color
  :config
  (defun my-colorize-compilation-buffer ()
    (when (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode)
      (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point-max))))
  :hook (compilation-filter . my-colorize-compilation-buffer))
```

Answer (score 7):

Riffing on @gavenkoa's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397737/ansi-coloring-in-compilation-mode#answer-20788581):

```
(when (require 'ansi-color nil t)
  (defun my-colorize-compilation-buffer ()
    (when (eq major-mode 'compilation-mode)
      (ansi-color-apply-on-region compilation-filter-start (point-max))))
  (add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'my-colorize-compilation-buffer))
```

This will not block errors but will still not raise an error if ansi-color is unavailable. Personally, I find the wildcard catch semantics of `ignore-error` distasteful.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020, the most modern way appears to be the `xterm-color` Emacs package.

See [my answer on the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710493/19163) for details.

Comment: Marked solution worked for me before 2019, but it wrecked on my setup today: `ansi-color-names-vector` is just ignored. I'm grateful alternative solution exists.