# Emacs: Missing Colors in Compilation Mode

Tags: emacs, terminal, textcolor, ansi-colors, compilationmode

Why i'm missing color features in emacs compilation mode whereas gnome-terminal its all fine.
This is the [code](https://gist.github.com/rhoit/5649111) which i wrote to generate the test.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXNp7.png)

.emacs I have following lines as suggest in [ANSI Coloring in Compilation Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397737/ansi-coloring-in-compilation-mode).

```
(require 'ansi-color)
(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()
  (toggle-read-only)
  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (toggle-read-only))
(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)
```

Comment: What's the value of your TERM variable in your terminal? `echo $TERM`

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that your emacs supports 256 colors?: `M-x list-colors-display`
Did you try to change the `tty-color-mode` to 256? CF: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html

Comment: 256-colors is supported by `emacs -nw` when I set the variable to TERM="xterm-256colors".
I haven't checked the `tty-color-mode`

Comment: how to change `tty-color-mode` can't figure out :/