# ANSI coloring in emacs start-process output buffer

Tags: emacs

I am running a process from within emacs which uses ANSI color codes in its output.

I'm using `start-process` to create the process, and provided a custom buffer name for the process's output

```
(start-process "foo" "*Foo*" foo-command foo-args)
```

If I open `*Foo*` buffer, the ANSI color codes are printed in their raw format to the buffer

```
^[[36msome output message^[[m
^[[1;35msome output message^[[m
^[[1;34msome output message^[[m
```

I see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408008/955273) it is possible to add colorization to a buffer; however I'm unsure as to how to do it with a buffer created using `start-process`

Is it possible to convert those ANSI color codes to colorised output in my `*Foo*` buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like the linked answers had any solutions not involving `comint-mode`.  You can use `ansi-color-apply-on-region` to colorize the output buffer, eg.

```
(set-process-sentinel
 (start-process "foo" "*Foo*" foo-command foo-args)
 (lambda (p _m)
   (when (eq 0 (process-exit-status p))
     (with-current-buffer (process-buffer p)
       (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome, literally copy-pasted your snippet and it worked!

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately (and quite obviously given the mechanics of the code) the buffer will display the control codes whilst the process is executing, and only afterwards, once complete, call `ansi-color-apply-on-region`. Do you know if it's possible to apply the `ansi-color` transformations "on-the-fly"?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I think perhaps the easiest way would be to just start the buffer in `comint-mode`.  Otherwise, you can make a `process-filter` and apply the color in your filter.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that will display the colors while the process is executing (rather than after the process is complete and calling `ansi-color-apply-on-region`)

The key is the last line: `set-process-filter`.

```
(defun runserver ()
  (interactive)
  (setq *server-buffer* (get-buffer-create "server"))
  (with-current-buffer *server-buffer*
    (ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
    (comint-mode))
  (let ((default-directory "~/server/"))
    (setq *server-process*
          (start-process-shell-command
           "server" *server-buffer* "./run_server")))
  (set-process-filter *server-process* 'comint-output-filter))
```

A process filter function is a function that receives the standard output from the associated process. All output from that process is passed to the filter. The default filter simply outputs directly to the process buffer.