# Correct node.js object output in emacs (Debian)

Tags: node.js, emacs, debian, output

I have node js code:

```
console.log(1);
console.log("1");
```

and run it in emacs M-x compile (node file.js)

I take output:

```
^[[33m1^[[39m
1
```

So, only strings output is correct, not objects, in Terminal output fine. It was be fine in emacs too in the past.

I have current debian testing enviroment

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.2.2
```

And node:

```
$ node -v
v10.1.0
```

Please, help!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788581/113848) do what you want?

Comment: @legoscia Yes, it is!