# Emacs shell mode showing unwanted char

Tags: shell, emacs

my emacs shell mode screen shot ...
[image: emacs shell mode screen]

Normal shell looks like this...
[image: shell mode normal]

I have .emacs file empty..

emacs version 24.5.1

I already tried this 
[Why does shell mode display some rubbish code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663005/why-does-shell-mode-display-some-rubbish-code)

[i copy the code provided in solution of above question in my .emacs file but its not working for me...]

Comment: Do echo $TERM and post the results.

Comment: xterm-256color        <------                  this is output of "echo $TERM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is the unicode not the escape codes that aren't displaying. You can change the `process-coding-system`. From your shell buffer, enter <kbd>C-x RET p</kbd> and select `utf-8-unix` for process read and write.

If that results in the proper display, you may want to add something like the following to your init file

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

See this [article](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/working-coding-systems-unicode-emacs) for further details.