# Magit diff doesn't show characters correctly

Tags: git, emacs, magit

When I run magit-status through emacs (gui or command line) and show a diff for a file, the color codes don't get escaped properly. Therefore, the whole diff is filled with `^[[`'s and that makes it impossible to see what's going on.

Here's what I've tried:

- If I run a regular `git diff`, in terminal colors are displayed correctly.
- Problem occurs for both GUI and in terminal (`-nw`)
- I have updated to `magit-20140305.1300` from the elpa repo, through the emacs package manager.
- I have tried with both different emacs themes, with no change.
- I have tried tweaking the `magit-item-highlighting`, as suggested on a different bug [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/pull/114).

I am using [bbatsov's prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude), but have updated magit, as stated above.

Any one know what could be causing this, and how I could fix it?

Comment: The problem occurs in both. I've written it in the first sentence, but I can see that it's unclear. I'll fix that.

Comment: Just guessing. Try doing `M-: (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))`

Comment: maybe by requiring ansi-color ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072648/cucumbers-ansi-colors-messing-up-emacs-compilation-buffer

Comment: Hadn't time to try it, as the marked answer below solved it. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have set one of the git variables `color.ui` or `color.diff` to `always`, and should change that back to `true` so that you get coloured diffs when useful (in a shell) but not when not useful (pretty much everywhere else, including magit).

Or better yet unset the variable completely using e.g. `git config --unset color.ui`.