# Invalid chars on compile command in Emacs

Tags: emacs, compilation

I am trying run a test (RSpec) in Emacs using the `compile` command, but there is a problem with the output; see [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3wkyi87c8sxzdu/Screenshot%202014-05-10%2001.00.44.png).

I tried to put this in my `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)    
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

And I use ttt-format too.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072831/1937596

Comment: Thanks @artscan. I didn't had found this post. Sorry for duplication.